# Context Broker FI: Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)

Tags: fiware-orion

I have stopped a virtual machine with CentOS running an instance of Context Broker. Upon relaunching the system with the enabler, the latter gives a Fatal Error. See the below log:

```
# contextBroker
INFO@13:18:32  contextBroker.cpp[1348]: Orion Context Broker is running
INFO@13:18:32  mongoGlobal.cpp[164]: Successful connection to database
INFO@13:18:32  contextBroker.cpp[1157]: Connected to mongo at localhost:orion
INFO@13:18:32  mongoGlobal.cpp[483]: Database Operation Successful ({ conditions.type: "ONTIMEINTERVAL" })
INFO@13:18:32  rest.cpp[901]: Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)
```

I'm working on the 4.1.2 version of Orion, CentOS 6 running in VirtualBox. Running with **su** because I get a permission denied on a log file error. For info, I have enabled bridging network connection just before the VM reboot.

Is it the fact that the broker was not closed correctly that there is something blocking its restart? (PS. yes I know that there is a nearly exact same error message in the administration guide, but I don't see any solutions there)

Thank you!

EDIT: one solution that works is uninstalling the contextBroker package and installing it again. I wish there was a cleaner way!

EDIT: this problem reproduces every time I kill the contextBroker application - then every time restarts don't help, reinstalling the package does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is no other instance of the broker running (ps aux | grep contextBroker), using the same port.
If there is another instance of the broker running, then the port will be taken and the REST initialization will fail.

About running as root because of log-file permissions ... Why not simply change the owner of the log-file instead?

Comment: 1)would the contextBroker start automatically on boot if I don't add it to any startup scripts? if no, there is no reason why the port would be blocked and unblock itself when the broker is uninstalled. but I'll check that; 2)for the log-file:I'm not a linux person and I do what I can to survive ;)

Comment: you're right with process killing, thank you. what is misleading is that by launching the broker with `contextBroker` it launches a service in the background, rather than an application one can kill with `^C` as I expected.