# Fatal error when starting orion context broker

Tags: daemon, systemd, fiware, fiware-orion

My orion context broker does not start and when I enter the command 
`/etc/init.d/contextBroker start` I get this message

```
[root@context-broker ~]# /etc/init.d/contextBroker start
Starting contextBroker (via systemctl):  Job for contextBroker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status contextBroker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The `systemctl status contextBroker.service` commannd gives this message

```
[root@context-broker ~]# systemctl status contextBroker.service
● contextBroker.service - LSB: run contextBroker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-24 11:38:50 UTC; 1min 11s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9782 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 11:38:47 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: Starting LSB: run contextBroker...
May 24 11:38:48 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[9782]: contextBroker is stopped
May 24 11:38:48 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[9782]: Starting...
May 24 11:38:48 context-broker.novalocal su[9788]: (to orion) root on none
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[9782]: Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid...irectory
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: contextBroker.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[9782]: pidfile not found[FAILED]
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: run contextBroker.
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit contextBroker.service entered failed state.
May 24 11:38:50 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: contextBroker.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Also the `/tmp/contextBroker.log` file looks like this

```
time=2019-05-24T11:41:12.971Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[1753]:restStart | msg=Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)
```

I checked if mongodb is running and it is running correctly.
**UPDATE**
With some searching I realised I had to kill the pid of the process and after I did that the service successfully starts according to the messaags but I find it doesnt actually work. When I ask for the status I get the following:

```
[root@context-broker centos]# /etc/init.d/contextBroker status
● contextBroker.service - LSB: run contextBroker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-05-26 18:34:49 UTC; 4min 56s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16295 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16319 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 26 18:34:47 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: Starting LSB: run contextBroker...
May 26 18:34:47 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[16319]: contextBroker is stopped
May 26 18:34:47 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[16319]: Starting...
May 26 18:34:47 context-broker.novalocal su[16325]: (to orion) root on none
May 26 18:34:49 context-broker.novalocal systemd[1]: Started LSB: run contextBroker.
May 26 18:34:49 context-broker.novalocal contextBroker[16319]: Starting contextBroker...                         [  OK  ]
```

The log file has the same message as previously.
With some searching again I believe the cause is that the service doesnt have a daemon(??). So if that is the case how do I add one?

Comment: Normally when getting the `error starting REST interface`, it's because there is already a broker running, which means the port is already taken. Make sure there is no broker already running. If not, try to turn on all traces (-t 0-255 -logLevel DEBUG) and we'll take another look (add to DAEMON_ARGS in /etc/init.d/contextBroker).

Comment: as @kzangeli mentioned, the mentioned problem is because of a contextBroker is already running. refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230272/context-broker-fi-fatal-error-error-starting-rest-interface) for more details.

Comment: @kzangeli you are right. I think your comment should be copy-pasted to an actual answer to the question.

Comment: In the end I simply created a new VM and installed orion there so I don't actually know if these would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when getting the error starting REST interface, it's because there is already a broker running, which means the port is already taken. Make sure there is no broker already running.